# Configuring Ubuntu 12.04 so that it recognizes the recently installed icc compiler

Tags: bash, command-line, compiler

I have an Ubuntu 12.04. I installed the icc compiler (composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080) but when I try to compile using it I get the message :

> icc : command not found.

I've read somewhere that when you install a new software you have to make something so that the OS gets aware of it, like modifying the bashrc file or something, but how to do it?

Comment: Thanks for the info, but why is my question Off-topic?

Comment: Because IMO it's more about linux than programming! Have a look here too, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

The compiler could be installed in any set of directories. Just look for it by using find:

```
find / -name icc -executable
```

Then you'll get a line like so:

```
/some/random/directory/icc
```

Just modify your `$PATH` variable like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/some/random/directory"
```

**N.B**: You are adding the directory to your path, not the `icc` executable.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the Intel compiler without specifying a destination directory, it should be in `/opt/intel`. Then run the following command

```
source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

to setup your environment correctly for using `icc`. Add the line to your `.bashrc` so that is gets run in every terminal you open.

Comment: Same problem here (`icc: command not found`). Doing `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64` didn't fix it. What else could be going on? I didn't get any error messages when I installed the Intel composer, so I'm puzzled. (Using Ubuntu 12.04 on a cloud instance.)

Comment: Oops, scratch that: I thought I had installed the Intel composer but it seems I only installed Intel MKL (facepalm...). So the reason I can't find icc is that I don't have icc.